# Uncaught (in promise) Error: call revert exception when calling smart contract function

Tags: smartcontracts, ethers.js, hardhat

I realise others have posted this error but not of the suggested fixes have worked.

Testing on localhost network

Uncaught (in promise) Error: call revert exception [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="fetchNftsForSale()", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.6.0)

My project is based from this https://dev.to/edge-and-node/building-scalable-full-stack-apps-on-ethereum-with-polygon-2cfb and code for this part is near identical

My issue deviates from others who have posted in that it works when the site is first loaded. It will call the fetchNftsForSale() method and return an empty array. No problem.

It's only after an nft has been minted and then going back to the page to display nfts for sale that the error occurs.
Doesn't make sense as the contract address is still the same

I've looked at the causes listed here but nothing stands out a being the cause. https://docs.ethers.io/v5/troubleshooting/errors/#help-CALL_EXCEPTION

Also this has been working previously and has only just stopped and I'm not sure what could have changed.

From what I can see, the provider is connected to the same network as like I said, the function call works when before signing transactions to create items.

I've created unit tests for minting, listing, buying and they all work.

I've also tried various different versions of Hardhat and ethers.js

Call to contract:

```
 const loadProperties = async () => {
    const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider()          
    const tokenContract = new ethers.Contract(nftaddress, NFT.abi, provider)    
    const marketContract = new ethers.Contract(nftmarketaddress, PropertyMarket.abi, provider)                       
    const data = await marketContract.fetchPropertiesForSale()
```

Smart Contract:

```
 function fetchNftsForSale() public view returns (MarketItem[] memory) {
  uint itemCount = _tokenIds.current();
  uint unsoldItemCount = _tokenIds.current() - _itemsSold.current();
  uint currentIndex = 0;

  MarketItem[] memory items = new MarketItem[](unsoldItemCount);
  for (uint i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
    if (idToMarketItem[i + 1].owner == address(this)) {
      uint currentId = i + 1;
      MarketItem storage currentItem = idToMarketItem[currentId];
      items[currentIndex] = currentItem;
      currentIndex += 1;
    }
  }
  return items;
}
```

Dependencies:

```
 "dependencies": {
"@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "^2.0.4",
"@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle": "^2.0.1",
"@openzeppelin/contracts": "^4.5.0",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
"@testing-library/react": "^12.0.0",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
"axios": "^0.24.0",
"chai": "^4.3.4",
"ethereum-waffle": "^3.4.0",   
"ethers": "^5.6.1",
"hardhat": "^2.8.2",
"ipfs-http-client": "^55.0.0",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
"react-scripts": "5.0.0",
"solc": "^0.8.12",
```

Comment: Please edit the question and show the `fetchNftsForSale()` source code (including its dependencies), how you call it from your JS method, and check if your provider is connected to the same network as the contract is deployed.